# How to add Value to the UI components through code?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, plist

I am rendering my UIComponents some of them are custom UIComponents like radio button,Check box from a plist.How can I add values programmaticaly inorder to display that value when rendered?

Comment: Show the content of the plist and an image of what do you want to achieve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.